# Cloudkit new record notification

Tags: notifications, cloudkit, subscription

I am about ready to update my app with CloudKit new record notifications. before I publish it should I delete the subscription I used to test it?

Answer (score 0):

**You can delete it, yes.** But if you are asking this question, you might be overlooking something with subscriptions.

I always create CloudKit subscriptions programmatically in my app when it starts up (through a method called from `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`). I set a static name for the notification like `taskNotification` for each `recordType` so that the same subscription gets overwritten with each app launch.

This is useful because this code will run for every user on every device so that their devices gets registered to receive the notifications.

It also ensures the subscriptions get created in the **Production** environment on CloudKit after you migrate to it.

If you are manually creating and deleting CloudKit subscriptions, you may not be allowing your users to subscribe their devices properly. Just thought I'd point that out.

Good luck!

Comment: Don't you get an error if the sub already exists?  You're getting new subs and overwriting the old one?

Comment: Yes, there is an error when you create a subscription with the same name, but you can safely ignore it. If you use the same subscription name, you can just create and save them. You don't have to fetch the existing one first. CloudKit will just overwrite the old one.